# What is the way to import interfaces from an external angular2 module included in an app module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, interface

I have defined a external common Angular2 module using typescript. I have a folder with interfaces in it. I have import the module in my root application module. Do I have to browse to the common Angular2 module folder and import the interfaces manually from the common module folder or will I be able to reference it directly? Eg:

AppCommonModule -> has interfaces in interfaces folder
AppModule -> imports -> AppCommonModule

How do I reference interface in my components?
`import {myInterface} from './my/path/to/appcommonmodule/folder'`?

OR is there another way to just reference it some other way?

Comment: Depends on how and where the interface is declared. If it's in an external module then `import {myInterface} from './my/path/to/appcommonmodule/folder'`  is what you need

Comment: I have created a interface in a common module. I have imported the angular2 module module in the root module. Do I have to still point to the path of the interface file or is there a best practice tweak available?

Comment: Angular exports all interfaces from a file export { xxxIncludesTypescriptInterfaces } from './src/core'; and not as a bundle. Is that the only hack?

Comment: If you're asking about putting it into an NgModule, then no you cannot do that. Don't try to organize your app around NgModule, the whole concept is a half-baked hack. Just use ES Modules and appropriate conventions to structure your application. Then put the necessary bits into NgModules to keep angular happy.

Comment: Yeah trying that now. Thanks.